# CSS focus pseudo-class overriden in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, select

Some time in May 2020 Chrome made a change to its CSS management.

The CSS of an input field that is focused and selected is now overridden by the O/S (in my case MacOS) appearance setting for selected elements.

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <style>
         input.a { color:red; background-color:white; }
         input.a:focus { color:white; background-color:green; }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <input class=a type=text value='abcdef' onfocus='this.select();'>
      <input class=a type=text value='abcdef' onfocus='this.select();'>
   </body>
</html>
```

With the new Chrome the font color is changed to black. It remains white in other browsers. Any workaround ?

Comment: overridden by the OS?  Do you mean its overridden by the User Agent Style Sheet?  I'm not on a mac so can't test it there.  Works fine in my chrome on pc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Input font color in chrome on mac is still white.  It is the font color for highlighted text that is black.  Try adding this css to control the highlight color and the highlighted font color:

Source: [overriding-the-default-text-selection-color-with-css](https://css-tricks.com/overriding-the-default-text-selection-color-with-css/)

```
::selection {
  background: #3a3a3a;
  color: white;
}
```